# The derby database

Tags: java, netbeans

In the IT class room I constantly hear chat about the derby database not being built for netbeans. I write code in java and becuase I am learning to implement databases and I have the oppurtunity to be taught sql code. My question is, is the derby database not meant for netbeans and if not why why? So far it works fine for me. Our education system is a bit out of order so I like to be well informed about things.(You don't have to worry about making sense about the last statement).I use the database for recording details in shop and company scenarios so far. So answer could relate to this.

Comment: never heard something like this. Netbeans works pretty well with derby.

Comment: Whoever said that, clearly has no idea what she/he is talking about and probably never has used Derby or NetBeans.

Comment: But that is what our deparment of education all the people from unversity that are telling the department are saying. I don't believe them but i guess they had a more extensive use than me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Java DB(Derby) database** is Oracle's supported distribution of Apache Derby. Java DB(Derby) is a fully transactional, secure, standards-based database server, written entirely in Java, and fully supports SQL, JDBC API, and Java EE technology. The Java DB database is packaged with the GlassFish application server, and is included in JDK 8(except Mac OS X) as well.

There is a whole official NetBeans IDE Tutorial about `Working with the Java DB(Derby) Database`. Whoever has suggested you those incorrect details,he might not have got to work with Derby Database OR might be a fan of Oracle/MySQL,etc. databases! But,I and all the commentators post suggest you to move frankly with Derby database as there is no such problem!

Also,I am leaving you the official tutorial's link---> [Official NetBeans IDE Tutorial on Java DB(Derby) Database](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html)